# ASP.NET Identity Confirmation Email Is Plain Text Instead of HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In an ASP.NET MVC5 C# application I am using the standard code for sending confirmation emails when a user registers, something I've done in multiple projects:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

Normally when the recipient receives the email, it's content-type is text/html. However, in this one application, the emails arrive with content-type text/plain and the content is not rendered as html, it is rendered as plain text. It should like this:

Please confirm your account by clicking [here](https://localhost:44309/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=8b126243-1f78-4e42-87d2-ab3c7c350f99&code=tokengoeshere)

But it looks like this:

```
Please confirm your account by clicking <a href="https://localhost:44309/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=8b126243-1f78-4e42-87d2-ab3c7c350f99&code=tokengoeshere">here</a>
```

I searched the docs but cannot find any information that indicates why this would be or indeed how to change this behavior.

I also updated to the latest version of the Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core (2.2.1) thinking that might help, but it didn't have any effect on the issue.

I also tested sending from a Google Apps email account for a different organization (which I use for other apps with this exact same code to send this confirmation email and know it sends as html) in case there are some settings in there that matter.

Any ideas on why it sends as text/plain and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code for EmailService.SendAsync?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - all the code is in my post. The UserManager.SendEmailAsync function is part of the ASP.NET Identity V2 library. In fact, that code in my post is default code that was already present in the Account controller when I made the application - I didn't even write it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - your comment in addition to the answers from user1666620 and @Daniel pointed my in the right direction. I didn't put it all together until Daniel told me to look in IdentityConfig.cs, so I'll give him credit for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is likely with the mail service/api you're using. I have used several and they generally have either an optional htmlBody parameter or an isBodyHtml parameter. If you specify which one you're using, or provide the code for the SendAsync Methos in the EmailService class (in IdentityConfig.cs), it'll probably be easy to point you in the right direction.

If your stuck with plain text, you can send plain text with a url and the client will often convert it into a link for the user. Outlook and gmail do this.

So, it would look like this instead:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account:" + callbackUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me to IdentityConfig.cs where I set mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true in the SendAsyc method. The other answers/comments were very helpful as well, but it was your post that put it all together for me so I'll award you the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you were able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 7):

The problem more than likely isn't with your Identity, it is probably just with the mail function itself. Have you set the `MailMessage.IsBodyHtml` property to true?

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail, subject, body);
message.IsBodyHtml = true; // here
```

This will set the body of the email to be rendered as HTML. By default, the property is false, so you need to explicitly declare it to be true.

Comment: Thanks, but I never handle the MailMessage in my code; it's all handled in the ASP.Net Identity V2 library's UserManager.SendEmailAsync function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - your comment in addition to the answers from deramko and @Daniel pointed my in the right direction. I didn't put it all together until Daniel told me to look in IdentityConfig.cs, so I'll give him credit for the answer.

Comment: Someone might find important to know that SmtpClient can receive a MailMessage in its SendMailAsync method. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SendGrid API to send HTML type emails and they also provide transactional templates.

Links

https://sendgrid.com/

Even advised in the Asp.net core doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use links to refer answers because there is always the possiblity that these links are not accessible in the next week, months or years.