# Html not getting correctly inserted into email when using the default asp.net mvc template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

Using the default mvc code for confirming email addresses on registration but when the email gets sent it isn't showing the html.
[image]
Template MVC code:

```
string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" +
                    callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

Send Email Async:

```
 public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {

        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        return client.SendMailAsync("email here",
                                    message.Destination,
                                    message.Subject,
                                    message.Body);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

When looking through some of the other questions on SO, I changed my send code slightly so that I could set the body to allow html but I still have the same issue

```
  public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = message.Body;
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        return client.SendMailAsync("email here",
                                    message.Destination,
                                    message.Subject,
                                    msg.Body);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

TIA

Comment: If you're not sure about anchor link, you can pass the token URL into the body like this: `await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking here: " + callbackUrl)`. In the last code sample, try using `return client.SendMailAsync(msg)` instead of using old pattern.

Comment: To add to Tetsuya's answer, you probably also need to set the "from" email like msg.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem more likely depends on which email service/API content you've currently using. In case `SendEmailAsync` method still sending confirmation email as plain text instead of HTML, you can embed the confirmation URL together with body message and let user's mail client automatically convert it to a link like this:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking here: " + callbackUrl);
```

Another way to send email body as HTML is setting `IsBodyHtml` property to `true` inside `SendAsync` method as shown below:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService 
{
    // other stuff

    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Subject = message.Subject;
        msg.Body = message.Body;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        msg.To.Add(message.Destination);

        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(msg);
        }

        // other stuff
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

NB: Ensure the `IdentityConfig.cs` file containing `SendAsync` method is available in `App_Start` directory of your project (see [this full example](https://github.com/JustMaier/MVC5-SPA-Angular/blob/master/SPAuth/App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs)).

Related issues:

[ASP.NET Identity Confirmation Email Is Plain Text Instead of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192836/asp-net-identity-confirmation-email-is-plain-text-instead-of-html)

[Email Confirmation with MVC 5 and Asp.net Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295236/email-confirmation-with-mvc-5-and-asp-net-identity)

Comment: Removing the anchor tags does work but then I'm still left with an ugly link that could be cleaner. Also, as you can see by the second example, I've tried using the IsBodyHtml  and I still had the same issue.

Comment: Seems that your second code sample doesn't include complete `MailMessage` instance to be passed as `SendMailAsync` method argument, it only passing `Body` property instead. As shown in complete `IdentityConfig.cs` given above, `MailMessage` instance which includes `IsBodyHtml = true` passed into `SendMailAsync` to enable HTML mode as body message.